# how to find out how many lines are in a variable

Tags: python, string, python-telegram-bot

I'm doing a Telegram bot and I want to print string in Inline keyboard. I have a variable `text` which can change and I want to chack how much lines(string) in variable as it can do with it `0<name<2` and do restrictions. How can do it?

I could make it with len(), but it show me `list index out range`

```
text="head,hand,..."

selectKeyboard = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup( row_width=1)

if 0<name<2:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name']),callback_data="first")

    selectKeyboard.add(one)

if 0<name<3:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="second")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two)

if 0<name<4:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="second")
        three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " ,callback_data="three")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two,three)

if 0<name<5:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  "+,callback_data="second")
        three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " ,callback_data="three")
        four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " , callback_data="four")

    selectKeyboard.add(one,two,three,four)

if 0<name<6:
    for i in range(len(text)):
        one=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[0]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="first")
        two=types.InlineKeyboardButton(text=str(text[1]['name'])+"  ",callback_data="second")
        three = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=str(text[2]['name']) + "  " ,
            callback_data="three")
        four = types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=str(text[3]['name']) + "  " ,
            callback_data="four")
        five=types.InlineKeyboardButton(
            text=str(text[4]['name']) + "  " ,
            callback_data="five")

    selectKeyboard.add(one, two, three, four,five)
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can not understand what you want. Please check your grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following piece of code is not doing what you imagine, in fact it'll just return `False`, because `name` is a `string` and you're comparing it against integers:

```
0 < name < 2
```

Instead, you should test for the number of variables, like this:

```
text = "head,hand,..."
num_vars = len(text.split(','))

if 0 < num_vars < 2:
    # same for all the other comparisons
```

Comment: Thanks you.  But I want to ask you about how it for  list or dict?

Comment: What do you mean, list or dict? I don't see that in the code you posted. If it's for a different part of the code, please post that as a new question.

Comment: Yes, i didn't post about list or dict, but I have some values in list and I want to do it for list, but i can't to find examples how it do

Comment: "to do it"... to do _what_, exactly?

Comment: Look, I have a data [{'id': 'fd65865b-0f43-468b-80a5-04d5c9f90086', 'vendorId': '232231', 'name': 'магазин-кафетерій', 'location': {'settlement': 'Київ', 'addressLine': 'м.Київ вул.А.Ахматової 35'}, 'freeVisit': False}, {'id': '2a2d898c-853c-453b-a8c3-0acd0e1ebc8a', 'vendorId': '232830', 'name': 'магазин', 'location': {'settlement': 'Київ', 'addressLine': 'м.Київ вул.Радунська,13-А'}, 'freeVisit': False}, in list. I want to know how much value "name" in this list. How do it?

Comment: Please post a new question, with sample input and the expected output. In the new question explain what do you mean with 'how much value "name" in this list'. It's not clear at all.